# regex - Compilation failed: assertion expected at offset 6

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)'s pattern ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840808/php-detect-html-in-string-and-wrap-with-code-tag/22842599?noredirect=1#comment34844508_22842599)) to wrap HTML tags in string.

```
$html = <<<EOD
    $str
EOD;

    $pattern = <<<'EOD'
    ~
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<self>    < [^\W_]++ [^>]* > )
        (?<comment> <!-- (?>[^-]++|-(?!->))* -->)
        (?<cdata>   \Q<![CDATA[\E (?>[^]]++|](?!]>))* ]]> )
        (?<text>    [^<]++ )
        (?<tag>
            < ([^\W_]++) [^>]* >
            (?> \g<text> | \g<tag> | \g<self> | \g<comment> | \g<cdata> )*
            </ \g{-1} >
        )
    )
    # main pattern
    (?: \g<tag> | \g<self> | \g<comment> | \g<cdata> )+
    ~x
EOD;
```

After implementing this method, I got an error `Compilation failed: assertion expected after (?( at offset 6`. What's wrong with this pattern?

Comment: What is your pcre version? (search with phpinfo)

Comment: I thought you're not there.I've checked phpinfo and this is everything about pcre `PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support enabled
PCRE Library Version 6.6 06-Feb-2006`.

Comment: Ok, it's a know bug for pcre version <7.2, I will post an other solution (assuming that the DEFINE syntax is the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, it seems that PCRE versions < 7.2 have this kind of bug with the DEFINE syntax.

You can write the same pattern like that:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?:
    (?<tag>
            < ([^\W_]++) [^>]* >
            (?> (?<text> [^<]++ )
              | \g<tag>
              | (?<self> < [^\W_]++ [^>]* > )
              | (?<comment> <!-- (?>[^-]++|-(?!->))* -->)
              | (?<cdata> \Q<![CDATA[\E (?>[^]]++|](?!]>))* ]]>)
            )*
            </ \g{2} > # second group from pattern start (<tag> is 1st)
    )
  | \g<self> | \g<comment> | \g<cdata>
)+
~x
EOD;
```

Comment: Should I use this or upgrade the PCRE version? Which one is better? Thank you.

Comment: I think upgrading your php version is a good idea, you are probably using a PHP version < 5.3?

Comment: It is not so old. You can try the 5.4.6 or more recent, as you like.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you for your enthusiasm.